# Entity Framework Automatic Safe Navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework intelligently and automatically handle safe navigation in certain cases?

Assuming the following EF entities:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

and assuming a clean database state before the following code is run, why does the first query below execute successfully, while the second query throws a NullReferenceException?

```
Blog blog1 = new Blog
{
    Name = "My Blog1"
};

await _db.Blogs.AddAsync(blog1);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

var query1 = from blogs in _db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)
            let post = blogs.Posts.OrderByDescending(post => post.Title).FirstOrDefault()
            where post.Title == "good post"
            orderby blogs.Name
            select blogs;
// This query will execute successfully.
await query1.ToListAsync();

var query2 = from blogs in _db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)
            let postTitle = blogs.Posts.OrderByDescending(post => post.Title).FirstOrDefault().Title
            where postTitle.Contains("Good")
            orderby blogs.Name
            select blogs;
// NullReferenceException will be thrown as a result of this call.
await query2.ToListAsync();
```

In the first query, I would expect the where clause to throw a NullReferenceException since there are no saved Posts, and therefore, the referenced post in the where clause should be null, but this is not the case. What are the rules for how EF handles "safe navigation" of properties?

Comment: In your first query you look for "good post" in the title and in the second one you are looking for "Good" instead of "good" or "good post".  Why the change?  I'd say the case change returns nothing thus query2 is null.

Comment: "Safe navigation" works only if the query is fully translated and executed as SQL. In your case it sounds like EF Core client evaluation issue.

Comment: In the first, the `where` is not even evaluated since `let` produces a null. In the latter, `let` cannot even be evaluated. The `FirstOrDefault` returns null so you can consider doing a shorthand null check `?`  like this: `.FirstOrDefault()?.Title`

Comment: @jcruz: is there documentation somewhere that verifies that a where clause is not evaluated when the let variable is null? I haven't been able to find any concrete documentation related to this.

Comment: @JoshFeldman check the SQL generated from that statement. It should generate a join that in the first case would just not return anything, hence, not get evaluated further by the db engine. On the latter, by using `FirstOrDefault` EF tries to retrieve the object into memory (.NET) and hence throws an exception when navigating to `Title`.